# Expose object fron Angularjs App to Protractor test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I am writing end-to-end tests for my AngularJS-based application using Protractor. Some cases require using mocks to test - for example, a network connection issue. If an AJAX request to server fails, the user must see a warning message.

My mocks are registered in the application as services. I want them to be accessible to the tests to write something like this:

```
var proxy;
beforeEach(function() { proxy = getProxyMock(); });

it("When network is OK, request succeeds", function(done) {
    proxy.networkAvailable = true;

    element(by.id('loginButton')).click().then(function() {
        expect(element(by.id('error')).count()).toEqual(0);
        done();
    });
});

it("When network is faulty, message is displayed", function(done) {
    proxy.networkAvailable = false;

    element(by.id('loginButton')).click().then(function() {
        expect(element(by.id('error')).count()).toEqual(1);
        done();
    });
});
```

How do I implement the `getProxyMock` function to pass an object from the application to the test? I can store proxies in the `window` object of the app, but still do not know how to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading and understanding the testing process a bit better, it turned to be impossible. The tests are executed in NodeJS, and the frontend code in a browser - Javascript object instances cannot be truly shared between two different processes.

However, there is a workaround: you can execute a script inside browser.

First, your frontend code must provide some sort of service locator, like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
       .service('proxy', NetworkProxy)
       .run(function(proxy) {
           window.MY_SERVICES = {
               proxy: proxy,
           };
       });
```

Then, the test goes like this:

```
it("Testing the script", function(done) {
    browser.executeScript(function() {
        window.MY_SERVICES.proxy.networkAvailable = false;
    });

    element(by.id('loginButton')).click().then(function() {
        expect(element.all(by.id('error')).count()).toEqual(1);
        done();
    });
});
```

Please note that when you use `executeScript`, the function is serialized to be sent to browser for execution. This puts some limitations worth keeping in mind: if your script function returns a value, it is a **clone** of the original object from browser. Updating the returned value will **not** modify the original! For the same reason, you cannot use closures in the function.